# what difference does it make in NavStack(move_base) with frame_id as map vs odom

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, costmap, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We set global_frame for different nodes of the NavStack. Below are the ones I am eager to know about and how they affect the system.

Costmap params:

```
/global_costmap/global_frame: map vs odom
/local_costmap/local_frame: map vs odom
```

planner params:

```
/DWAPlannerROS/global_frame_id: map vs odom
/GlobalPlanner/global_frame_id: map vs odom
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369319/what-difference-does-it-make-in-navstack(move_base)-with-frame_id-as-map-vs-odom/) by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-14**:
If you are using an `external map` to naviagte, then it makes sense to set the `global_frame` paramter in the costmap configuration file to `map`.

**Comment by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on 2021-01-14**:
Thanks for response @skpro19 . I load the map obtained from `gmapping` using `map_server` package.

1. what do you mean by external map? Do you mean using a map different from the map being used by SLAM map?
2. Is it fine to use map as `global_frame` in the costmap configuration even if I am using ONE single map for amcl in my NavStack?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-14**:
By `external_map`, I mean any map that is being published on the `/map` topic.

Whenever you are running a program (i.e. node) that publishes on the `/map` topic, and you want to use that `/map` topic to build your `global_costmap`, you would need to set the `global_frame` parameter to `/map`.

Sometimes, it could also happen that you don't really care about the `map`, and just want to operate the bot in the `odom` frame. In such cases, you would need to set the `global_frame` (for your `global_costmap`) to `/odom`. You would also need to manually set the `width` and `height` for the `global_costmap`.

Does that make sense?

You could also try to visualize the `global_costmap` on `Rviz` for more clarity.

**Comment by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on 2021-01-14**:
Hi @skpro19,

It totally makes sense now and even answers my question. So basically if we do not have a external grid_map we use odom frame.

One of the use case example of this would be when we totally rely on GPS for localization and few range sensors for obstacle avoidance via local_costmap and global_costmap.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

refer to the comments for answe.

---

Originally posted by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) with karma: 45 on 2021-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0